# How to prove the following statement is true by either contradiction or contraposition method?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, if $x \leq y$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor = \lfloor y \rfloor$, then either $\lfloor 2x \rfloor = \lfloor 2y \rfloor$ or $\lfloor 2x \rfloor = \lfloor 2y \rfloor − 1$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The word is not "contraposition", it is "contrapositive".

Comment: @user247327: *Contraposition* is also correct here: contraposition is the conversion of an implication to its contrapositive.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lfloor x \rfloor = \lfloor y \rfloor = k \implies k \le x,y < k+1 \implies 2k \le 2x,2y < 2k+2 \implies$$$$\implies \lfloor2x \rfloor\in\{2k,2k+1\}; \ \ \lfloor 2y \rfloor \in \{2k,2k+1\}$$
Now, it is clear that the claim is true.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to prove the result by proving the contrapositive, but a direct proof (as given by **VIVID**, for instance) is much simpler. To prove the contrapositive, suppose that $x\le y$, $\lfloor 2x\rfloor\ne\lfloor 2y\rfloor$, and $\lfloor 2x\rfloor\ne\lfloor 2y\rfloor-1$. Let $n=\lfloor 2x\rfloor$, so that $n\le 2x<n+1$. Clearly $\lfloor 2y\rfloor\ge n$, and by hypothesis $n\ne\lfloor 2y\rfloor\ne n+1$, so $\lfloor 2y\rfloor\ge n+2$. Now $n\le 2x<n+1$, so $\frac{n}2\le x<\frac{n}2+\frac12$, and $2y\ge n+2$, so $y\ge\frac{n}2+1$, and there are now two possibilities.

- If $n=2k$ is even, $k\le x<k+\frac12<k+1\le y$, so $\lfloor x\rfloor=k$ and $\lfloor y\rfloor\ge k+1$.
- If $n=2k+1$ is odd, $k+\frac12\le x<k+1<k+\frac32\le y$, so $\lfloor x\rfloor=k$ and again $\lfloor y\rfloor\ge k+1$.

In both cases $\lfloor x\rfloor\ne\lfloor y\rfloor$, and we’ve proved the desired contrapositive.